# Building form with Datepicker in CQ5

Tags: aem

I am pretty new in CQ5. I am using CQ version 5.6. I have to build a form with following features
1. Start Date
2. End Date
3. Customer Name
4. Gender
5. URL
I am using CQ5 form component for the same. For features 3,4 and 5 I am using text-field, radio buttons and Link component from sidekick. However for  1 and 2 (dates) I am not sure what to do. I am looking for a datepicker kind of an option but I am not finding them in the form components group. Is there any way to add such a component?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is the CQ.form.DateTime widget. It is available as datetime xtype.

But it is not available through the sidekick, because the datewidget is not a component but an ExtJs widget which can be included into a component dialog through a simple xtype include. 
Making it available through the sidekick requires to create a simple "date and time" component with the datetime widget in the component's dialog definition.

The author-summary component in the geometrixx-media example project is a good example as it's dialog definition uses the datetime widget to render the publishing date and time.  Just check out /apps/geometrixx-media/components/author-summary/dialog/items/publishedDate via vlt or access the path through crxde.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.DateTime provides you the full documentation for this widget.